# Different row > col disposition by screen size (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to have two differents row > cols disposition depends on screen size.
Example, i got actually this for md screen :

```html
<div class="row align-items-md-center">
  <div class="col-6">1</div>
  <div class="col-2">2</div>
  <div class="col-2">3</div>
  <div class="col-2">4</div>
</div>
```

And for mobile i would like :

```html
<div class="row align-items-md-center">
  <div class="col-6">1</div>
  <div class="col-2">4</div>
  <div class="col-2">2</div>
  <div class="col-2">3</div>
</div>
```

Someone already got this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `display: flex` with `order` property to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using order property works for flex layouts.

Here take a look at this, here I have added classes for columns and according to the requirement I have changed the order of the `.div-3` and `div-2`. By default all flex-items have 0 order, so I changed the order of those div to 1 in the media query so that the divs having order 1 will come after the divs having order 0.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .div-2, .div-3 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row align-items-md-center">
    <div class="col-6 div-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-2 div-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-2 div-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-2 div-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this, without any additional classes:

```css
    .row {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
      .row > div:nth-child(2), .row > div:nth-child(3) {
        order: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row align-items-md-center">
      <div class="col-6">1</div>
      <div class="col-2">2</div>
      <div class="col-2">3</div>
      <div class="col-2">4</div>
    </div>
```